# Reshuffling a list in Python

Tags: python

Suppose we have a list `cid = [1,1,1,2,2]`. The goal is loop over the list and each time replace the element at the cursor position with each one from a pool of candidates. The pool is all other elements not equal to the one in focus plus one more which is not contained in `cid`. For example for `cid = [1,1,1,2,2]`I want to end up with:

```
[[2 1 1 2 2]
 [3 1 1 2 2]
 [1 2 1 2 2]
 [1 3 1 2 2]
 [1 1 2 2 2]
 [1 1 3 2 2]
 [1 1 1 1 2]
 [1 1 1 3 2]
 [1 1 1 2 1]
 [1 1 1 2 3]]
```

What I have written is:

```
arr = np.empty((0, len(cid)), int)
m = max(cid)

# Loop over the list
for i, j in enumerate(cid):
    # make a pool of candidates
    pool = set([x for x in cid if x != j])

    # add a new element
    pool.add(m+1)

    # construct the new list
    for idx in pool:
        a = cid[:i] + [idx] + cid[i+1 :]
        arr = np.append(arr, np.array([a]), axis=0)

print(arr)
```

Is there a better way to write this please? A real case scenario involves a list of length around 3000 containing almost 50 different integers (quite likely not sequential)

Comment: @jpp: OP's code works fine for me in Python 3.4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the same output as the other answers, and as the OP, but the combination of numpy replacement and memoizing previously seen results can get a faster result on large inputs. When I tried the originally given code it took ~0.25 seconds when the given `cid` was `range(50)`, the timing results of different input `cid` on the code below is shown below. The given code is a lot faster than the originally given code, but how much depends on the given `cid`. The distribution of the input will matter, the more times you see a particular input the more that memoizing will help you :)

It's noted in the code, but when you get to large inputs you should probably start to break up the arrays being calculated and write them out somehow.

Also, from rough timing analysis it looks like most of the time goes into creating the `array` variable with `np.ones`. The actual replacement using numpy is quite fast. Hooray numpy :)

```
import numpy as np
cid = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
# cid = range(600)       # ~0.23 seconds
# cid = range(100) * 6   # ~0.08 seconds
# cid = range(100) * 30  # ~1.1 seconds
# cid = range(300) * 10  # MemoryError

# Or whatever extra element you want
extra_element = max(cid) + 1
# By putting the set into an array format the pool[pool != j] step below
# becomes very fast
pool = np.array(list(set(cid)) + [extra_element])
# This is the number of available candidates to replace any individual element
num_available = len(pool) - 1
# Memoize results we've seen before
seen_elements = {}

# Create an array to hold the output. It's possible that this can get too
# large to hold in memory all at once, so you might want to consider breaking
# this up (maybe create a new array each for loop and then write it somewhere?)
array = np.ones((len(cid) * num_available, len(cid)), dtype=int) * np.array(cid)

# Replace the operational range each loop with the saved value, or populate
# the saved value as necessary
for i, j in enumerate(cid):
    lower_bound = i * num_available
    upper_bound = i * num_available + num_available
    try:
        array[lower_bound:upper_bound, i] = seen_elements[j]
    except KeyError:
        seen_elements[j] = pool[pool != j]
        array[lower_bound:upper_bound, i] = seen_elements[j]

print array

[[2 1 1 2 2]
 [3 1 1 2 2]
 [1 2 1 2 2]
 [1 3 1 2 2]
 [1 1 2 2 2]
 [1 1 3 2 2]
 [1 1 1 1 2]
 [1 1 1 3 2]
 [1 1 1 2 1]
 [1 1 1 2 3]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this! I appreciate the time you spent looking into this

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making a new set of candidates each time, create a master set before you enter the loop.  Each iteration, simply remove the unwanted element to get a set for that index position.

Also, I think you can clean up the replacement logic a *little*.  I tried using a product that would keep the head and tail constant and iterate through the desired index position, but that's not very readable.  I finally settled on essentially your own handling, but actually replacing the desired element each time and then appending a copy:

```
cid = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
master = set(cid + [max(cid)+1])

solution = []

for idx, val in enumerate(cid):
    print(idx, val)
    cand = master - {val}
    for elem in cand:
        cid[idx] = elem
        solution.append(cid[:])
    print(solution)
    cid[idx] = val
```

Output (line breaks inserted manually):

```
[[2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
 [3, 1, 1, 2, 2],
 [1, 2, 1, 2, 2],
 [1, 3, 1, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 3, 2, 2],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
 [1, 1, 1, 3, 2],
 [1, 1, 1, 2, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: ahhh now i see what he was trying to do ... i just couldnt tell from the description and the posted code